# Oracle transfer all varchar to nvarchar

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to change all varchar columns to nvarchar in the database.
The "cause" of the transfer is a high level decision that all data must be in unicode.
In out databases we use only 2 languages and all works perfectly...
There are several ways to do so, but i want to ask if there is any advantage in using nvarchar instead of varchar in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Why not changing the database CHARACTER SET to `AL32UTF8` then all your VARCHAR are Unicode.

Comment: Alternatively you can create a new database with a unicode characterset en export/import the data into the new database.

Comment: Is setting CHARACTER SET to AL32UTF8 will affect only new data or existent data too? Is there will be any storage growth? Also i asked about benefits of using nvarchar instead of varchar, if there any...